# Ошибка при компиляции . Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyttsx3

Использую Visual studio code .Запускаю через него все работает прекрасно , но при открытии exe файла созданного с помощью pyinstaller'a  просто программа сразу закрывается . Успел заскришотить.

Код

```
import pyowm
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import os
r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
owm = pyowm.OWM('57a26ac9da8f1b8fcc9de495ddc5c947', language="ru")


engine.say("Здравствуйте , как вас зовут ? ")
engine.runAndWait()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Здравствуйте , как вас зовут ")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        name = r.recognize_google(audio,language="ru-RU")
        print("Вы сказали : {}".format(name))
    except:
        print("Ошибка перевода речи")

    #name = input("Здравствуйте , как вас зовут ? ")




    engine.say("Скажите в каком городе  хотите узнать погоду ")
    engine.runAndWait()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Скажите в каком городе  хотите узнать погоду ")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        place = r.recognize_google(audio,language="ru-RU")
        print("Вы сказали : {}".format(place))
    except:
        print("Ошибка перевода речи")


    #print("Введите в каком городе  хотите узнать погоду: ")


    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]


    engine.say(  name + " В городе " + place + " сейчас " + 
    w.get_detailed_status())
    engine.runAndWait()
    print(name + " В городе " + place + " сейчас " + 
    w.get_detailed_status())
    engine.say(name + " Температура сейчас в районе "+ str(int(temp)) +" 
    градусов")
    engine.runAndWait()
    print(name + " Температура сейчас в районе "+ str(temp) +" градусов")

    if temp < 10:
        print("Холодно, оденься")
        engine.say("Холодно, оденься")
        engine.runAndWait()
    if temp > 20:
        print("Жарко, включи кондиционер")
        engine.say("Жарко, включи кондиционер")
        engine.runAndWait()
    else:
        print("Нормально")
        engine.say("Нормально")
        engine.runAndWait()

    input()
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
  File "c:\users\ilifra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
```

Comment: Вы используете библиотеку pyttsx3, но вы делали импорт этой библиотеки во время компиляции программы?